# show that the the sequence $z_n=i\sqrt{2}+\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n$ is cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that The sequence $z_n=i\sqrt{2}+\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n$ is cauchy sequence

my attempt: for proving $z_n$ is cauchy-sequence we have to show that $|z_n-z_m|<\epsilon$

so consider $|z_n-z_m|=\left|i\sqrt{2}+\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n-i\sqrt{2}-\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^m\right|$

=$\left|\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n-\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^m\right|$

but from here how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n =\sqrt{2} i , b_n =\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n . $ Then $a_n$ is constant sequence and $|b_n |=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n \to 0.$ Therefore $z_n =a_n +b_n $ is a Cauchy sequence as sum of two convergent sequences.

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazu..great ..thank you